# Related to scheduling :How insert a list in spite of one of its element is having exception

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

I have set scheduling on Lead in which on daily basis a SMS and a mail gets deliver as a reminder to client. But when there is an error in email id and salesforce display an error that mail id is not correct, scheduling get aborted and system throws an exception. It means no client will receive any reminder mail and sms because of one wrong email id.

so can we do something that apex do not stop executing scheduling process because of a wrong mail id. Other clients who has correct mail address receive the reminder as usual.

My code is given below. No trigger is used.
Scheduling class:

```
global class LeadReminderSchedule implements Schedulable{   

list<Lead> schedule = new list<Lead>(); 

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx)
    {
        try{
            CronTrigger ct = [SELECT Id, CronExpression, TimesTriggered, NextFireTime
                                 FROM CronTrigger 
                                 WHERE 
                                 Id = :ctx.getTriggerId()];

            system.debug('--cron expression--'+ct.CronExpression);
            system.debug('-cron trigger run--'+ ct.TimesTriggered);

            LeadReminderMail lrm = new LeadReminderMail();
            lrm.sendMail();

            LeadReminderBatchSMS lrbs = new LeadReminderBatchSMS();

            Integer scopeSize =100;

            Database.executeBatch(lrbs, scopeSize); 
            //cleaning(); // to clean deleted or aborted schedule jobs.

        }catch(exception ex){
            system.debug('--Exception is--'+ ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Mail sending class ( not complete):

```
            for(Lead scheduledLead : tempLead){
            if((scheduledLead.client_interest__c == 'Relevant' ||
                scheduledLead.Client_Interest__c == 'Serious')
                && ((scheduledLead.First_Follow_Up_Date__c != null &&
                     scheduledLead.First_Follow_Up_Date__c == todayDate &&
                     scheduledLead.Second_Follow_Up_Date__c != todayDate)
                    ||  ( scheduledLead.Second_Follow_Up_Date__c != null &&
                        scheduledLead.Second_Follow_Up_Date__c == todayDate))){
                system.debug('--Client interest--' + scheduledLead.client_interest__c); 

                system.debug('--mail to lead contains--' + scheduledLead);

                String[] toAddresses = new list<string>{scheduledLead.email};
                String[] ccAddresses = new list<string>{scheduledLead.CCEmail__c};

                Messaging.Singleemailmessage msg = new Messaging.Singleemailmessage();
                msg.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
                if(scheduledLead.CCEmail__c != null 
                    && scheduledLead.CCEmail__c != ''){
                    ccaddresses=scheduledLead.CCEmail__c.split(',');
                    msg.setCcAddresses(ccAddresses);
                }   
                msg.setTargetObjectId(scheduledLead.id);
                msg.setTemplateId(mailTemplateMap.get(templateName));
                msg.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(orgUserEmailId.get(scheduledLead.OwnerID));

                MessageList.add(msg);
            }
        }
        system.debug('-mail list size-'+ MessageList.size()+'--mail details--' + Messagelist);
        sentMail(messageList);

    }catch(exception ex){
        system.debug('--Exception is LRM-- ' + ex.getMessage());
    }

}

public void sentMail(list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> detailOFMail){
    System.Debug('-list size-'+ detailOfMail.size()+'---messageList 2---'+ detailOFMail );
    try{
        if(!StopRepetition.hasExecutedOnce()){
            Messaging.sendEmail(detailOFMail);
            System.Debug('---Send Email---');
        }
        StopRepetition.setExecutedOnce();
    }catch(exception ex){
        system.debug('--Exception is LRM-- ' + ex.getMessage());
    }   
}

}
```

SMS batch class is also there if someone wants I will update my question.

Kindly help me to know the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Rohit

In your method `sentMail`, the statement `Messaging.sendEmail(detailOFMail);`

should be changed to

`Messaging.sendEmail(detailOFMail,false);`  The second argument is optAllorNone and defaults to true meaning if one email fails, they all fail; if false, then good emails go through and bad ones don't

In addition, you could use this Utility class to validate email addresses and avoid even trying to send

```
//  --------------------------------------------------------
//  validateEmail - source: http://salesforcesource.blogspot.com/2010/01/utilizing-apex-pattern-and-matcher.html
//  --------------------------------------------------------
public static Boolean validateEmail(String email) {
  Boolean res = true;
  System.debug('Entering Util.validateemail on: ' + email);
  String emailRegex = '^[a-zA-Z0-9._|\\\\%#~`=?&/$^*!}{+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'; // source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

  Pattern patt    = Pattern.compile(emailRegex);      // create a Pattern
  Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(email);              //then a Matcher

  if (!matcher.matches()) 
    res = false;
  System.debug('Leaving Util.validateemail res: ' + res);
  return res; 
}   

private static testmethod void testValidateEmail() {
  System.assertEquals(false,          validateEmail('abc.abc.com'));
  System.assertEquals(false,          validateEmail('ABC.ABC.COM'));
  System.assertEquals(true,           validateEmail('abc@abc.com'));
  System.assertEquals(true,           validateEmail('00@abc.com'));
  System.assertEquals(true,           validateEmail('simplewith+symbol@example.com'));
  System.assertEquals(true,           validateEmail('a.little.more.unusual@dept.example.com'));
  System.assertEquals(false,          validateEmail('postbox@com'));                              // unusual, actually valid but we ignore
  System.assertEquals(true,           validateEmail('!#$%&*+-/=?^_`{}|~@example.org'));           // unusual, actually valid 
  System.assertEquals(true,           validateEmail('Abc.@example.com'));                         // actually invalid but sfdc accepts this
  System.assertEquals(true,           validateEmail('Abc..123@example.com'));                         // " "
  System.assertEquals(false,          validateEmail('A@b@c@example.com'));
  System.assertEquals(false,          validateEmail('this is not allowed@example.com '));
```

}